# Projet in birds survey having trouble in code. how to store data like database system

Tags: c++, project, survey

How can I store my input in the following catagories i.e water,domestic etc.When I give information about water birds then I give information about domestic birds.but 2nd information overrides the first one.Is there any way to store data for catagory wise?

```
/* declaring header files */
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Bird{

    private:
        char name[50],colour[50],nature[50],location[50];
        float living_duration;

    public:
        int code;
        int set_info(){
            char name='\0';
            char colour='\0';
            char nature='\0';
            char location='\0';
            float living_duration=0.0;
        }
        int get_info(){
            cout<<"\nEnter bird's name: ";
            cin>>name;
            cout<<"Colour: ";
            cin>>colour;
            cout<<"Nature: ";
            cin>>nature;
            cout<<"Location: ";
            cin>>location;
            cout<<"Living Duration: ";
            cin>>living_duration;
            cout<<"Bird's code: ";
            cin>>code;
            }
        int display_info(){
            cout<<"\nBird's name: "<<name;
            cout<<"\nColour     : "<<colour;
            cout<<"\nNature     : "<<nature;
            cout<<"\nlocation     : "<<location;
            cout<<"\nLiving Duration  : "<<living_duration<<" year";
            cout<<"\nCode       : "<<code;
        }
    }obj[100];

int main(){
    int i,j,k,n,m;
    do{
           cout<<"\n\nWhat do you want to do\n1.Input bird's information"
               <<"\n2.Display\n3.Search\n4.Exit."
               <<"\n\nChoose appropriate number: ";
           cin>>n;

           switch(n){
              case 1://bird information
                 cout<<"Please Select Birds Category"<<endl;
                 cout<<"------------------"<<endl;
                 cout<<"1)Water\n2)Domestic\n3)prey\n4)treebased\n5)flightless\n6)migratory\n"<<endl;
                 cin>>m;
                    switch(m){
                    case 1:
                        cout<<"Enter the number of bird how many to input: ";
                        cin>>j;
                        for(i=1;i<=j;i++){
                        cout<<"\nInformation of Bird "<<i<<".\n";
                        obj[i].get_info();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        break;
                    default:
                        cout<<"Wrong choice!!\nPlease enter correct number.";
                        break;
                    }


               case 2://display
                  for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
                 {
                  cout<<"\nBird no "<<i<<".\n";
                  obj[i].display_info();
                 cout<<"\n";
                 }
                 break;

               case 3://search
                 cout<<"\nEnter the bird code: ";
                 cin>>k;

                 for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
                  {
                 if(k==obj[i].code)
                    {
                     cout<<"\nBird no "<<i<<".\n";
                     obj[i].display_info();
                     break;
                    }
                   }
                 if(k!=obj[i].code)
                   cout<<"Wrong code input...\n";
                  break;

               case 4://exit
                  break;

               default:
                  cout<<"Wrong choice!!\nPlease enter correct number.";
                  break;
             }

         }while(n!=4);
  }
```

Comment: You *do* know that arrays are zero-based? So that an array of 100 elements (like your global variable `obj`) will have indexes from `0` to `99` (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your concepts between bird *data* and a *container* of data.

In a *relational* database, you would have *tables*.  Let the columns of a table be represented by the data members of a structure.  A record (row) of the table will be an instance of the record structure:

```
class Bird
{
public:
  std::string name;
  std::string colour;
  std::string nature;
  std::string location;
  float       living_duration;
};
```

For the container or table, you could use `std::vector`:
  `std::vector<Bird> bird_table;`

Many relational databases also include *index tables* to speed up searches.  The index table will contain pairs, the key (or column value) and an index into the `std::vector`.  The C++ language has a handy container called a `std::map`:

```
std::map<string, unsigned int> name_index;
```

The `string` parameter represents the key or column type.
The `unsigned int` parameter represents the index into the database (a.k.a foreign key).

To retrieve a Bird record by name you access the index table first, then the vector:

```
   unsigned int database_index = name_index["crow"];
   Bird  crow = database[index];
```